# Automapper issue with abstract base class in version 4.0.X

Tags: automapper

I have a problem after updating to version 4 with inheritance. I have the following code:

```
public abstract class CarDA
{
}

public class StationCarDA : CarDA
{
}

public abstract class CarBL
{
    public CarBL(string type) 
    {
    }
}

public class StationCarBL : CarBL
{
    public StationCarBL() : base("stationcar") {}
}

Mapper.CreateMap<CarDA, CarBL>()
  .Include<StationCarDA, StationCarBL>();
Mapper.CreateMap<StationCarDA, StationCarBL>();

var dataAccessObject = new StationCarDA();

var result = Mapper.Map<CarDA, CarBL>(dataAccessObject);
```

Try it on dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p3JeNO

This worked in previous versions so that the result was a StationCarBL instance. Now I get the following error:

Mapping types:
CarDA -> CarBL
Test.CarDA -> Test.CarBL

Destination path:
CarBL

Source value:
Test.StationCarDA

Stack Trace:

[System.ArgumentException: Type needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args
Parameter name: type]

[AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException:

Mapping types:
CarDA -> CarBL
Test.CarDA -> Test.CarBL

Destination path:
CarBL

Source value:
Test.StationCarDA]

That message does not make sense to me. I have defined the CarDA -> CarBL mapping and why is it trying to map to CarBL which is abstract?

Comment: If I explicitly tell the mapper to construct a StationCarBL instance it works (https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q2wVkc), but this should not be needed as I have already told the mapper in the ".Include<StationCarDA, StationCarBL>()" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a bug in Automapper

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/819